# How do I programmatically set the Return Key for a particular UITextField?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I can't believe that this question hasn't been asked yet, but I have been unable to find it so that is my assumption.

I have created custom `UITableViewCel`l subclasses using Interface Builder. These each contain a `UILabel` and a `UITextField` and are used for our login screen.

On the first `UITextField`, I want the Keyboard Key to say `Next`. However, on the second `UITextField`, I want it to say "Done."

How do I programmatically change the value of the `Return Key` on the keyboard? I cannot use `Interface Builder`, since that would make both keys appear as `Done`.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use Interface Builder and set two different return key types for each UITextField.

Comment: Sorry did not read the question fully.... I have updated the answer now..

Answer (score 87):

For the first `UITextField`, Read  [THIS](http://www.neoos.ch/news/46-development/54-uikeyboardtypenumberpad-and-the-missing-return-key)  tutorial on how to create a button on a Keyboard. You can learn the logic from there and use a `Next` button instead of `Done` button.

```
   //if you just want to make it appear NEXT//

    textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
```

And for the second `UITextField`, use...

```
   // for DONE //

    textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
```

You can in general create and rename the button to anything, and make sure you give the right `IBAction` on the event that that button is pressed. In case you do create your own custom button, look at the tutorial above to learn about placing it in the right coordinates and stuff.

Comment: This is so infuriating. Please explain to me why "returnKeyType" isn't found anywhere in Apple's documentation?

Comment: This is Apple's documentation by the way: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html

Comment: And also, THANK YOU. I looked long and hard for this.

Comment: @user367817 It is in one of the protocols([`UITextInputTraits`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextInputTraits)) adopted by `UITextField`.

Comment: Oh yes. That is it. You can also check this example for all the various ways to use the UITextField and the way you can customize it http://iphonedevelopertips.com/user-interface/adjust-textfield-hidden-by-keyboard.html

Answer (score 5):

you have to invoke `[textView reloadInputViews];` after setting the return key type to update the keyboard return key appearance immediately.

DO IT AS FLLOW:

`textView.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
[textView reloadInputViews];`

Comment: incredible how nobody mentioned `reloadInputViews` in other answers.

Answer (score 2):

It can also be done by setting property in .xib file. You just have to set `Return Key` property of `UITextField` to `Next` under `Attribute Inspector`.

Answer (score 1):

In swift 4, the following code can be used for replacing the "Return button" on keyboard with "search button" or "done button":

```
yourTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.search
yourTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
```