# rename the return key Done

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I programmatically set the Return Key for a particular UITextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311015/how-do-i-programmatically-set-the-return-key-for-a-particular-uitextfield)

a simple question here :

how to rename the `UIReturnKeyDone` in the keyboard?

I want to change text from  "`Done`" to "`Login`"

Answer (score 4):

You cannot change the key to any arbituary value, however you can choose among one of these

From [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html)

```
   UIReturnKeyDefault,
   UIReturnKeyGo,
   UIReturnKeyGoogle,
   UIReturnKeyJoin,
   UIReturnKeyNext,
   UIReturnKeyRoute,
   UIReturnKeySearch,
   UIReturnKeySend,
   UIReturnKeyYahoo,
   UIReturnKeyDone,
   UIReturnKeyEmergencyCall,
```

Answer (score 0):

[image] 
.

You can set your return key only from these. If you want to rename your **return key** to **Login** then you have to make a **custom button (LoginButton)** then add it to just above on your keyboard with animation and on this button's click you just resign your keyboard by

```
[yourTextField resignFirstResponder];
```