# IOS Cordova access TextField and modify UIKeyboardReturn type

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, angularjs, cordova

I have a Cordova IOS application using AngularJS for the UI.

There's a login form with input fields that I want to access as UITextFields and modify their UIKeyboardReturnType. (as seen in [How do I programmatically set the Return Key for a particular UITextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311015/how-do-i-programmatically-set-the-return-key-for-a-particular-uitextfield))

When you tap on any of the login input fields, I want the UIKeyboardReturnType to be something different than the default one. Is this possible and how?

**What I tried so far:**

- the https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins/tree/master/keyboard plugin for reference and see if it's done there somehow, but I don't see any UITextFields.
- to go through every MainViewController subview recursively and find an UITextField and modify it but I didn't find any UITextFields to begin with

Cordova app uses: iOS 7 and newer.

Comment: html input fields aren't UITextFields

Comment: @jcesarmobile Yes, however aren't they represented as a UITextField in the UIWebView?

Comment: no, they are html components, not native components

Comment: @jcesarmobile I see. Welp, that's unfortunate :/. Thank you for the fast response!